# Scala JSON4S to return a triple during field deserialization

Tags: json, scala, parsing, null, json4s

I'm working with JSON4S and it handles missing fields correctly, when the corresponding object's field is an option.
I'm using

```
implicit val formats =
  Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) +
    new org.json4s.ext.EnumNameSerializer(E)
```

and `read[T](json)`.

It's perfect, except one thing. I'd like to designate between missing and `null` fields. What I'd like to have for each field of my `T` is to have something like a `Triple` instead of `Option`, where this triple would be either a `Some(t)`, `Missing` or `Nullified` in analogue to how `Option` works. I have no problem in defining such a structure, but unfortunatelly I'm not so familiar with how JSON4S works, or how could I (maybe) "intercept" the parsing of a field to achieve such a value-extraction.

As an alternative, it also would be great if the parser would set the corresponding field of `T` to `null` if the field is `field: null` instead of setting it to `None`. This would not feel Scalaish I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably implement a custom serializer for `T`. I would use the following format because it allows for more flexibility and [order independent](https://nmatpt.com/blog/2017/01/29/json4s-custom-serializer/) input:

```
import org.json4s.CustomSerializer
import org.json4s.JsonAST._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._

case class Animal(name: String, nrLegs: Int)

class AnimalSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Animal](format => ( {
  case jsonObj: JObject =>
    val name = (jsonObj \ "name") //JString
    val nrLegs = (jsonObj \ "nrLegs") //JInt

    Animal(name.extract[String], nrLegs.extract[Int])
}, {
  case animal: Animal =>
    ("name" -> animal.name) ~
      ("nrLegs" -> animal.nrLegs)
}
))
```

To handle null/empty values take a look at the [JSValue trait](http://json4s.org#guide). For null values you should match with `JNull` and for non present values with `JNothing`.